# disable auto-lock even when iOS app is not running?

Tags: ios, swift

I know I can disable an iOS device's auto lock when my app is up and running, like so:

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

My question is: is there a way from the app to disable the auto lock of the device (so, set it to never), even when the app is not running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; having an API for that would allow third-party apps to disable a security feature of the device. You can [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) if you’ve got a use case in mind, but it may not get far.